# Launch Python function using Gspread from excel via xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings, gspread

I am trying to launch a python function using Gspread from excel via xlwings. For the context, I am doing this to be able to import data from a google sheet 'database' into my hard-copy excel file. The function works perfectly when I launch it from a Python console but doesn't seem to work when I launch it from Excel via a macro using RunPython.

More precisely, I have added flags to see where was the problem:

```
def main():

 wb = xw.Book.caller()
 wb.sheets['Dashboard'].range('J3').value=0#used as a flag

 import gspread
 from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
 wb.sheets['Dashboard'].range('J3').value=1.5#used as a flag
 # use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
 scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
 wb.sheets['Dashboard'].range('J3').value=1.6#used as a flag
 creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
 wb.sheets['Dashboard'].range('J3').value=1.7#used as a flag
 client = gspread.authorize(creds)

 wb.sheets['Dashboard'].range('J3').value=1#used as a flag
```

The value that I get in my J3 cell after trying to run the program is 1.6, meaning that the line that causes the problem is:

```
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
```

The file client_secret.json is in the same working directory as both the python script and the excel file. If you have any idea on what could be the problem and how I can solve it, that would be great!

Thank you for the help!

Comment: `RunPython`'s working directory may vary and you can't set it from within xlwings just yet, so you need to use the full path for your json file.

Comment: That was the problem indeed! Is there any way that I can get the current working directory of the Python script via RunPython() though? That would be convenient if I want to distribute my code...

Comment: you should be able to use something like `os.path.join(os.path.dir(__file__), 'file_name')` in your script.

Comment: That works with :

    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified by @Felix Zumstein, the solution is to specify the full path of the 'client_secret' json file, possibly using os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file))